Why the traefik pod dns address are different with other pod dns in kubernetes
When I acsess the same domain in the same kuberetes, the traefik v2.10.1 pod dns are different with others, this is the traefik dns look like:
/ $ nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     100.100.2.136
Address:    100.100.2.136:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

and this is the other pod dns look like:
root@y-websocket-service-9654986bc-cf65m:/home/node/app# nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1

this is the traefik define in kubernetes v1.29.x look like:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: default
status:
  observedGeneration: 6
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2024-07-06T08:40:50Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-07-06T08:40:50Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2024-07-09T14:04:24Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-07-08T12:57:09Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet "traefik-5f6fd6d8f5" has successfully progressed.
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
      app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
        helm.sh/chart: traefik-10.1.1
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2024-07-09T14:04:02Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: traefik-config
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/traefik:v2.10.1
          args:
            - '--global.checknewversion'
            - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
            - '--entryPoints.metrics.address=:9300/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.web.address=:8000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp'
            - '--api.dashboard=true'
            - '--ping=true'
            - '--accesslog=true'
            - '--tracing=true'
            - '--log.level=DEBUG'
            - ‘--log.filePath=/opt/traefik.log’
            - '--metrics.prometheus=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics'
            - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
            - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              hostPort: 9300
              containerPort: 9300
              protocol: TCP
            - name: traefik
              hostPort: 9000
              containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: web
              hostPort: 8000
              containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: websecure
              hostPort: 8443
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/traefik
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsUser: 65532
            runAsGroup: 65532
            runAsNonRoot: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: traefik
      serviceAccount: traefik
      hostNetwork: true
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65532
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600

Am I missing something?

The Traefik containers are running with hostNetwork: true. That's why you see the host ip address rather than a private container ip addresses. You can read more about hostNetwork mode in the answers to this question.
